# Can I use Cobertura on Unit Tests with PowerMock?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, powermock, cobertura

## Problem

I am setting-up unit-test code coverage for an Android library which uses  **Robolectric** to run the tests and **PowerMock/Mockito** for mock-testing.

However, running unit-tests with **Cobertura** results in the following Exception...

```
:example:testDebugUnitTest
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.example.package.saas.Query$RemoveWordsType.__cobertura_init(Query.java)
    at com.example.package.saas.Query$RemoveWordsType.<clinit>(Query.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.TouchCollector.applyTouchesToSingleClassOnProjectData(TouchCollector.java:123)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.TouchCollector.applyTouchesOnProjectData(TouchCollector.java:110)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.ProjectData.saveGlobalProjectData(ProjectData.java:272)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.SaveTimer.run(SaveTimer.java:33)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.add(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:66)
    at java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Runtime.java:211)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.ProjectData.initialize(ProjectData.java:239)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.ProjectData.getGlobalProjectData(ProjectData.java:209)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.TouchCollector.<clinit>(TouchCollector.java:45)
    ... 11 more
```

...and the generated Cobertura report shows no coverage at all.
[image: Cobertura report with PowerMock]

---

Running the same testcase without PowerMock*, the tests run fine and the coverage report is generated successfully:
[image: Cobertura report without PowerMock]

​* i.e. commenting the tests using PowerMock, removing the `PowerMockIgnore` annotation, the `PowerMockRule` and the `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` invocation.

---

## Investigation

- I see that some users [fixed a similar issue](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues/25#issuecomment-27314766) by setting `forkmode="once"` in their testsuite.
  However, this is not the solution as I am using Gradle [which defaults on Java projects](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/How-do-you-set-Junit-forkmode-to-once-tp3203096p3203154.html) to [`ForkMode.ONCE`](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-542).
- Other users reporting a similar issue [fixed it by updating PowerMock to 1.5.4](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues/99#issuecomment-128363669).
  I tried downgrading to this version, but the issue remains.
- Finally, a similar issue was fixed by [explicitly specifying a dependency to `cobertura-runtime`](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues/94#issuecomment-51973447), but adding it didn't change anything either.

---

## Question

Is it possible to use **Cobertura** in conjunction with **PowerMock**?

- In that case, what am I missing?
- Otherwise, how should I measure code coverage with such a setup (Android *Library* + **Robolectric** + **PowerMock**)?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Gradle build, Powermock tests show up with 0% coverage. Would love to get this solved.

Comment: +1 for your very clear question. Could you share a basic project reproducing the problem (on github for example) ?

Comment: In you test cases are you extending class from PowerMockTestCase?

Comment: @gontard: I can do so, but it would take some time to extract the relevant parts from the current project. Would it help you troubleshoot this? I could also create gists of the buildscript and of a testcase if this is what you would like to see.

Comment: @MoralesBatovski: Not really, as I am following robolectric's instructions (https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/Using-PowerMock). Would you advise another approach?

Comment: I agree with @gontard that a POC would be great. Since that's time consuming, can you add to the question your test class meanwhile? That'd also help troubleshooting this!

Answer (score 1):

Right now, Android Studio integrates **jacoco** automatically to do code coverage.

You just need to add a few lines of code:

---

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco-android'
```

---

```
android {
   buildTypes {
      debug {
         testCoverageEnabled = true
      }
   }
}
```

More information here:

- http://blog.wittchen.biz.pl/test-coverage-report-for-android-application/

Comment: I tried your solution, but adding jacoco and running createDebugCoverageReport generates [an empty report]( http://i.stack.imgur.com/ACTcY.png). Apart from that, are you sure jacoco works for unit-tests (`test`) and not just for Instrumentation Testing (`androidTest`)? The article you linked does the latter, while I am trying to achieve the former *with Robolectric*.